# Google forms script on form submit - event does not have FormResponse object

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms, google-workspace

I have a google form, and have added a script to it.

I created a function:

```
    function myFunction(e)
    {    
      Logger.log(e);
    }
```

Then I went to Edit > Current Project Triggers

I added a new trigger, selecting myFunction, and the following settings:

- Select Event Source = From Form
- Select Event Type = On form submit

When I submit the form and check the logs, I see:

{authMode=FULL, source=Form, triggerUid=25580}

It does not have a **response** object

I have a number of other forms set up and are working and allow me to use the response object.  I haven't created a form in a while - and now I can't get them to work.  I've set them up the same as the others as far as I can see.

Any idea as to why I am no longer able to access the response object on the event?

Comment: Just to make 1,000% sure, can you try: `e.response.getId()` and see what happens.  If this is a bug, then you should submit a complaint on the [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues)

Comment: I think its broken.  I just tried to create a spreadsheet bound form.  When I tried to create the form I got a blank page. I closed that page and a form was created but not viewable.  Now when I "Submit" form nothing goes to the spreadsheet response page.  And the new trigger dialog is completely changed.  It takes up the whole browser window and sometime items are rolled off the screen.  Why did they have to fix something that wasn't broken.

Comment: I get an error saying the e.response is undefined.  
I will submit a complaint on the Issue Tracker.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug - I submitted an issue in the Tracker as suggested.  They have given a workaround until they fix it.

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/2/issues/118921815

Comment: Google search terms to safe the next person a few hours of their life by finding this sooner: Google script crashes when FormSubmit event response is used.