# Google Forms Script You do not have permission to call Form.getResponses

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to create a trigger for a Google Form to send the responses to an API endpoint when the form is submitted, but even before I get to the API call, I am having trouble accessing the form responses with a trigger. I have the below in my `code.gs` but I am getting the following error message:

`You do not have permission to call Form.getResponses`

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  Logger.log(e)
  Logger.log(e.source.getResponses())
}
```

The form, the trigger and the script were all made by the same account. There are a lot of posts about issues similar to this, but I have not found a simple, clear answer on how to solve it.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53138175 Might be a temporary issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure why, but I deleted the trigger and recreated it and now it works fine. One thing I noticed, was there was a pop-up (which was originally blocked by Chrome) asking for permissions. I allowed the permissions - perhaps that was the blocker, although I am fairly certain I did that the first time as well.

Before deleting and recreating the script, I did add:

```
 "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms",
     "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/forms.currentonly"
  ]
```

to the `appsscripts.json` in the Google Scripts project. Remember to "View -> Show Manifests File" if you can't see it